# ColdFusion RequestTimeout in component ignored or ineffective

Tags: timeout, coldfusion-9

We have several repos where individual pages (eg. scheduled maintenance operations) need to be allowed to execute longer requests (eg. 5 minutes).

However in one repo, setting requesttimeout to 360 seems completely ineffectual! No matter what we set this value to it timesout at 60.

```
<cfcomponent>

  <cfsetting requesttimeout="360" />

    <cffunction 
      name="doit"
      access="public" 
      returntype="string"
      output="true" >   

        <cfinclude template="arrComs.inc.cfm">

        <cfset strHTMLReport = '<ul>'>

        <cfloop array="#arrComs#" index="i">

        <cfscript>

          thisCom = CreateObject( 'component', i.fileSansExt );
          skvResult = thisCom.generate();

          // Sleep for 5 seconds to give MySQL a bit of breathing space
          sleep( 3000 );

        </cfscript>

        <cfset strHTMLReport &= '<li>' & skvResult.msg & '</li>'>

      </cfloop>

      <cfset strHTMLReport &= '</ul>'>

    <cfreturn strHTMLReport>

  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Any ideas? Where can I look to help diagnose this? How many locations can requesttimeout be set and why does it seem repo specific?

Comment: You need the request timeout in the code that calls the function, the code that defines it.

Comment: @AdamCameron I have just tried moving the `<cfsetting>` tag to inside the `<cffunction>` tag but still the same behaviour. Any more ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

**SOLVED: Deleted the same 1 line of code from 2 of the components that were called inside the loop. The lines set the RequestTimeout to 60, thus overriding the timeout set in the parent.**

Humble Pie Time: My mistake was to forget that the components that are called inside the loop also have a line of code with sets the timeout to 60 seconds. Although the error was reporting a timeout it was not clear exactly where. In hindsight I should have searched my code base for the number 60 and I would have found the 2 offending lines a lot sooner.

Further thinking, whilst researching this I found that CFLOOP and CFQUERY both have timeout limits which can be set so for thoroughness I also increased the timeouts on the MySQL queries in the component.

Further further thinking, components that were called earlier in the loop changed the requesttimeout for components that were called later.  So although I was diagnosing by inspecting the parent function and the function that it timedout on, I was not given any reason to suspect the components that were called previously in the process.